# Why the address of the pointer variable printed differently between two printf statements without any modification to the variable?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-address

In below simple c test program two printf statements return different values. ( check last four printf statements).

```
int main ()
{
    char c, *cc;
    int i;
    long l;
    float f;
    c = 'Z';
    i = 15;
    l = 7777;
    f = 9999999312;
    cc = &c;
    printf("\nc = %c, cc= %u", *cc, cc);
    cc = &i;
    printf("\nc = %d, cc= %u", *cc, cc);
    cc = &l;
    printf("\nc = %ld, cc= %u", *( long* )cc, cc);
    printf("\nc = %ld, cc= %u", *cc, cc);
    cc = &f;
    printf("\nc = %f, cc= %u", *(float *)cc, cc);
    printf("\n cc= %u", cc);
    printf("\nc = %f, cc= %u", *cc, cc);
    printf("\nc = %f, cc= %u", *(float *)cc, cc);

    printf("\nc = %f, cc using pointer  = %p", *(float *)cc, cc);
    printf("\nc = %f, cc using pointer  =%p", *cc, cc);

    return 0;
}
```

output : -

```
c = Z, cc= 755585903
c = 15, cc= 755585904
c = 7777, cc= 755585912
c = 97, cc= 755585912
c = 9999998976.000000, cc= 755585908
cc= 755585908
c = 9999998976.000000, cc= 4294967288
c = 9999998976.000000, cc= 755585908
c = 9999998976.000000, cc using pointer  = 0x7ffc37f4ace4
c = 9999998976.000000, cc using pointer  =0xfffffff8
```

I am running it in eclipse ide and using Ubuntu Linux.

Why does it behave differently?

Comment: UB. By the truckload.

Comment: Wow, wow. Slow down. `C` can't be learned by experimentation.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I assume he expects the values to be the same because the `cc` variable is not changed during the last two `printf` statements and yet the printed value is different (4294967288 vs 755585908).

Comment: If I add following two lines  printf("\nc = %f, cc using pointer  = %p", *(float *)cc, cc);
 printf("\nc = %f, cc using pointer  =%p", *cc, cc); I get following output                         c = 9999998976.000000, cc using pointer  = 0x7ffc37f4ace4
c = 9999998976.000000, cc using pointer  =0xfffffff8      which are again different..

Comment: They are different because the format specifiers don't match the arguments, which is UB.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Thank you for the answer. But I am still not clear. The only difference between last two lines are with respect to the "c" variable , one was with typecast and other was direct and there is no impact in the result but why it is impacting  cc address ?

Comment: As soon as the arguments don't match the format specifiers you enter the realm of undefined behaviour. Anything can happen then. But on some platforms it _may_ display the same values.

Comment: In the last `printf()`, you pass a `char` (which is converted to an `int`), and then tell `printf()` to format it as a `double`.  That has so many opportunities to confuse you and the compiler and the library — it is undefined behaviour; you're lucky the compiler didn't decide to reformat your hard disk (it's an undefined behaviour — fortunately for you, compilers don't often do that).  There's no point in speculating about the details.  What you show is laden with undefined behaviour.  Anything is an acceptable result.

Comment: Knowing more about how most C compilers generate assembly is useful but knowing how to correctly respond to a C compiler's warnings is much more useful. If your compiler isn't giving you at least a dozen warnings, then you're either not using it to the best of its ability or you need to get another compiler.

Comment: regarding: `f = 9999999312;` this statement is assigning a `int` to a `float`.  Suggest avoiding the implicit conversion and writing the statement as: `f = 9999999312.0f;`

Comment: regarding: `cc = &i;`  this is performing a mismatched assignment from 'address of`int' being assigned to a 'pointer to char'  Such oversights result in an implicit conversion.  When using `gcc`, with the option `-Wconversion`  the compiler will tell you about this problem

Comment: regarding: `printf("\nc = %ld, cc= %u", *cc, cc);`  the variable `cc` is a pointer to char.  so is NOT a `unsigned int`.  the proper format specifier is `%p` so the corrected statement would be: `printf("\nc = %ld, cc= %p", *cc, cc);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In several places you are using the wrong format specifier to `printf`.  In particular, on this line:

```
printf("\nc = %f, cc= %u", *cc, cc);
```

The first parameter has type `char`, but you use `%f` which expects a `double`.  Also, the second parameter has type `char *` but `%u` is expecting an `unsigned int`.  Using the wrong format specifiers invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That being said, here is what is most likely happening under the hood:

On most hosted implementations, floating point numbers are not pushed onto the stack the way integer types and pointers are, but are instead stored in a floating point register.

When you run the above `printf` command, both `*cc` and `cc` are pushed onto the stack because neither of them are floating point numbers.  When `printf` then looks for the first parameter it sees `%f`, so it retrieves a value from a floating point register.  Since you did actually pass a floating point value the prior time you called `printf` that value is still there, and that value happens to be the value you actually wanted to print, so that's what gets printed.

Then when `printf` goes to print the next parameter, it sees `%u` in the format so the value is pulled from the stack.  That value is `*cc`, which points to the first byte in the representation of `f`.

Assuming a `float` is a IEEE754 single precision floating point number, the value it contains is represented as `0xf8021550`.  The first byte of that is `0xf8`.  Since `cc` points to a `char`, which in your case appears to be signed, it is interpreted as a negative value.  When passed to `printf` the value is promoted to type `int`, so the actual value passed in is `0xfffffff8`, which is what you see being printed.

To reiterate however, the output you're seeing is undefined behavior.  The output could change if you build it on a different machine, use a different compiler, or just use a different optimization setting.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. has no failures from incorrect assignments and incorrect calls to `printf()`
3. the actual output is not passed to the terminal until the program exits, because all the format strings for the calls to `printf()` are missing the trailing '\n'.

Note: the proposed code was compiled on a 64bit system with the following command line:

```
gcc -ggdb  -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=gnu11 -pedantic -o "untitled2" "untitled2.c"
```

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    char  c;
    char *cc;
    int   i;
    long  l;
    float f;

    c = 'Z';
    i = 15;
    l = 7777;
    f = 9999999312.0f;

    cc = &c;
    printf("\nc = %c, cc= %p", *cc, cc);

    cc = (char*)&i;
    printf("\nc = %d, cc= %p", *cc, cc);

    cc = (char*)&l;
    printf("\nc = %ld, cc= %p", *( long* )cc, cc);
    printf("\nc = %ld, cc= %p", *(long*)cc, cc);

    cc = (char*)&f;
    printf("\nc = %f, cc= %p", *(float *)cc, cc);
    printf("\n cc= %p", cc);
    printf("\nc = %f, cc= %p", *(float*)cc, cc);
    printf("\nc = %f, cc= %p", *(float*)cc, cc);

    printf("\nc = %f, cc using pointer  = %p", *(float *)cc, cc);
    printf("\nc = %f, cc using pointer  = %p", *(float*)cc, cc);

    return 0;
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
c = Z, cc= 0x7fffb663ae2f
c = 15, cc= 0x7fffb663ae30
c = 7777, cc= 0x7fffb663ae38
c = 7777, cc= 0x7fffb663ae38
c = 9999998976.000000, cc= 0x7fffb663ae34
 cc= 0x7fffb663ae34
c = 9999998976.000000, cc= 0x7fffb663ae34
c = 9999998976.000000, cc= 0x7fffb663ae34
c = 9999998976.000000, cc using pointer  = 0x7fffb663ae34
c = 9999998976.000000, cc using pointer  = 0x7fffb663ae34
```